# Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load /anaconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mkl/../../../libmkl_rt.so.1

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I have a standalone executable python script with a shebang using python's executable inside anaconda's binaries.
it runs fine when I run it as-is in an interactive session but when I run it inside a larger script (using its absolute path. permissions are as they should be else it wouldn't run in the previous case) it produces this error.
I tried changing LD_PRELOAD and tweaking PATH as mentioned in other solutions but it didn't work.
P.S. I can neither update anaconda packages nor change current settings.
anaconda version: 2021.11

I tried changing LD_PRELOAD and tweaking PATH as mentioned in other solutions but it didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.